# @DataJpaTest: how to stop loading unneeded @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, spring-data-jpa, configurationproperties

In a SpringBoot (2.2.1,2.2.2) application a sliced @DataJpaTest doesn't run because a bean holding @ConfigurationProperties could not be created.

The test:

```
@DataJpaTest
public class FooCustomerServiceTest
{
    @Autowired
    FooCustomerRepository repo;

    @Test
    void findAll()
    {
       repo.findAll();
    }
}
```

When I try to run the test I get a

> No qualifying bean of type 'foo.appconfig.AppInfoConfig' available

`foo.appconfig.AppInfoConfig`

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.info")
public class AppInfoConfig
{
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

It is referenced by one `@Component` not related to the test.

The `foo.Application` that is used has no special annotations

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class Application
{
    public static void main( final String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
    }
}
```

As sliced tests only scan for certain components (@Entity and @Repository in case of @DataJpaTest) 'AppInfoConfig' is not scanned. That's ok but why is it tried to be injected to another controller that is neither a entity nor a repository?

**How can I enable the correct creation of AppInfoConfig or disable the creation at all?**

NB: A `@TestConfiguration`having a `@Bean` method does work but is not really handy if you have a lot of those `@ConfigurationProperties` classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you have `@ComponentScan` on your `SpringBootApplication`? Doing so overrides the configuration that is applied on it, including the filter that customizes classpath scanning in slice tests.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing what I experienced.

My problem is exactly the same as the OP explained and moreover the cause of the problem is also the same as the accepted answer.

But in my case, The `@ComponentScan` is required because the application needs to scan components outside the application package.

```java
@ComponentScan(
        basePackageClasses = {
                Application.class, // this application
                some.other.NoOp.class // resides in a dependency
        }
)
@SpringBootApplication
class MyApplication {
}
```

I spent several hours what's wrong with my `@DataJpaTest` even peeped this thread.

My solution is using a custom context replacing the main application.

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootConfiguration
@Slf4j
class MyDataJpaTestConfiguration {

}
```

And imports it from the `@DataJpaTest` class.

```java
@Import(MyDataJpaTestConfiguration.class)
@DataJpaTest
abstract class MyEntityDataJpaTest {
}
```